# How to import "var" variables from another file ".txt, .js"?

Tags: javascript, variables

in an platform game "TyranoBuilder" i can use some javascript ! So i can use like

```
var bb = (ORANGE)
```

and the game can take that variable by

```
f.Test = (bb);
```

My question is how i can import that bb variable from outside of game, from an url ! ? EXAMPLE

```
var bb = src"http....a.js"
```

so i can edit it everytime i want ! :| Sorry my English, but i really need ! i have read some things like in html firs.js second .js ! but the second js is in the game !

Comment: Not sure if I've understood correctly but you need to include the script tag `<script src="http....a.js"></script>`. next script will have variable `bb`, defined. Each script share same JavaScript context.

Answer (score 1):

No: that's what JSON is for.

Don't make a text file, make a .json file and put your variable in that as an object property, like a lot of programs already do. E.g.

```
{
    bb: "orange",
    fg: "green"
}
```

Then you can either directly import it if you're using something like Node:

```
const config = require('./config.json');
...
let thing = config.bb;
```

Or you can separately load the file from url (e.g. using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) if you're working in the browser) and then use the `.json()` function on the fetched result to get the data as plain JS that you can access like any other part of your program:

```
function startGame(config) {
  // entry point that starts your actual application
}

fetch("/config.json").then(data => data.json()).then(config => startGame(config));
```

Comment: Thanks for attention, but can you make me an example with everyfile ? i mean ok i create the .json or .js file with variables, but in the game i use var = (THE VARIABLE) how i call it from that file ?

Comment: you don't call things "from a file", you load in the file and turn it into normal JS, after which you access all your data the same way you access anything else. I've edited in two examples.

Comment: ... Too hard for me ... !  because i can't edit all the game, it only allow me use some java script and html ! even php ! i need something easy to replace that line "var bb = (ORANGE)" with some link that i can change variable from outside of game i mean in the hosting i go i open variables.json or js i edit save & close ! and the game will take them from that file... :| its so hard ? or maybe i can't explain better, because the game is visual novel platform, like Ren'py etc etc ! its in html/java only

Comment: If basic Javascript is too hard for you, then the solution is to learn Javascript. Not to demand solutions that make no sense. What you're seeing here is very simple, normal modern Javascript. If you already know PHP or older JS, you can learn the basics of modern JS in a week or two. Do yourself a strong favour, and sit down with a modern tutorial to learn how to use Javascript.

Comment: You right, but i don't use java ! Listen 2 sec please LOOK this "a.js
var myemail="xyz@gmail.com";
localStorage.setItem("email",myemail); == b.js
var x=localStorage.getItem("email");
alert(x) // output=xyz@gmail.com   this works ! but must be all 2 in the game what i need something likt  var x="urlstorage.getitem("email)"; jut to take 1 varibel from outside sedon .js file !

Comment: Javascript is not Java. They're two _completely_ different languages. You asked how to do something, and here's the thing you need to remember: answers on Stackoverflow are not just for you, they are for _everyone who has the same problem_, because those people will have searched the web, found this question, and expect to find the right answer. If basic JS is too hard, then you need to learn basic JS, because everyone else who finds this answer will be able to follow along just fine. I'm not going to tell you how to do the wrong thing, in the wrong way. That's not what SO is for.